# Similar to UNIQUE customers by date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create an organizer to my payments sheet, it's a sheet that receives all payments and I want to show only the last payment for each user, I want do this to know how much time user stay with us!

I don't have idea how to do it, I'm trying use UNIQUE but this doesn't work fine!

Can you help me?

Demo sheet:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/169FgYI4v43WnFhAlcfrXnOtzvBKMNbQBvGsQ7W41HcE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set up a new sheet called "Erik Help" with this formula in F1 (highlighted bright green):

`=ArrayFormula({"Client name"\"Payment date";VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B;B2:B<>""));SORT(B2:C;2;0);{1\2};FALSE)})`

You can see that the formula generates the headers first.

Underneath that, the unique list of clients ...

`UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B;B2:B<>""))`

... is looked up within a `SORT` of the client and payment data, sorted descending by date (which leaves the most recent dates at the top and working down).

The virtual range `{1\2}` is returned, which is each name and date from the `UNIQUE` list.

Since `VLOOKUP` only returns the first match it finds (if any), you'll always get the most recent date per client.

Comment: thanks for your help, now im trying change to my "default table"

Comment: Paulo, if my solution above solved the issue that you posted about as you posted it, please take a moment to mark the answer as "Best Answer." This will serve to mark the posted issue as resolved, as well as helping future site visitors with similar issues more easily find this answer. Regarding your comment "now, I'm trying to change...,"I would encourage you to explain your full issue whenever you post, rather than adding to it later. In addition, keep in mind the forum is designed to give many people a little help, rather than being a place to get extended work done at no cost.

Comment: If you have a different question, I encourage you to start a new post that explains that new issue fully. You may include a link back to this post. But the new post should fully describe the issue as if the link option were not available. This helps Stack reach its goal of making information easy for other site visitors to find, rather than having to read down through comments to find answers to other questions or extension questions.

Comment: erik, im trying adapt to this collumns: DOMAIN IP HTTP STATUS CDN Starter CDN Pro CDN Enterprise   Custom Package EXPIRY DATE like "customers" tab

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where is the data I should use within your sheet. So let's work on dummy table (it's in your spreadsheet as sheet 'Dummy'):

First I take a list of transaction and get unique client names:

```
=unique(B2:B)
```

[image]

Then I use vlookup formula to search for the first appearance of the client on payment list.
Ifna is used to hide error messages
Arrayformula makes vlookup possible to work on whole column without copying.

```
=ArrayFormula(ifna(vlookup(G2:G;$B$2:$C;2;true)))
```

[image]

Comment: hi Krzysztof Dołęgowski 
thansk for your help i want to find within all single customers the date that will expire later. for example: in client1 i want 05/03/2021 and not 06/02/2021